# How to plot and/or slice an array that is segmented by a locigal array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, plot

I have a set of data stored in two arrays. The data consists of x and y coordinates that belong together. Within the data there are sections that belong together. I have a logical array (same length as x and y) which contains information on which indices of the arrays should be regarded as a sections. Now I want to plot this data taking into account its segmentation. Is there a fast and easy way to extract and/or plot the segments seperately? I know I could do this in a loop, but maybe there is a more effective way.

Here is a small example. In this example we would have three sections in the data:

```
x = 1:1:10;
y = ones(size(x));

segmentation = logical([1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1]);

figure;
hold on;
plot(x, y, 'b-o', 'DisplayName', 'input data');
plot(x(1:4), ones(1,4), 'r--x', x(9:10), ones(1,2), 'r--x', 'DisplayName', 'desired data/plot slices');
legend;
```

section1 is x(1:4) and y(1:4) → Plot as lines

section2 is x(5:8) and y(5:8) → Don't plot

section3 is x(9:10) and y(9:10) → Plot as lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the creation of multiple line objects for their respective segments, all with identical entries in the `legend`, is not an important feature of the example but a byproduct of the solution you think you're looking for, you can plot all segments at once with gaps between by setting the out-of-segment entries to `NaN`:

```
xSegment = x;
xSegment(~segmentation) = NaN;
plot(xSegment, y, 'r--x', 'DisplayName', 'desired data/plot slices');
```

or avoid creating an intermediate variable by simply exploiting divide-by-zero (creating `Inf` values, which are also not plotted):

```
plot(x ./ segmentation, y, 'r--x', 'DisplayName', 'desired data/plot slices');
```

If you do need the resulting objects to be separate, a loop is probably the tidiest solution available to you.